# Can we get RSA public key associated with device from google iot core

Tags: google-cloud-platform, iot, google-cloud-iot

Actually, I have a device and its associated public key on Google IoT Core. Is it possible to get that public key from any script using the service account (and respective registry). Is it restricted keys on google-iot-core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. An example using [python iot client](https://googleapis.dev/python/iot/latest/gapic/v1/api.html#google.cloud.iot_v1.DeviceManagerClient.get_device):

```py
from google.cloud import iot_v1

client = iot_v1.DeviceManagerClient()

name = client.device_path('my-project', 'my-location', 'my-registry', 'my-device')

response = client.get_device(name)

# Here you can see the credentials
print(response.credentials)
```

An example using [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/gcloud-examples):

```sh
gcloud iot devices describe my-device --project=my-project --region=my-location --registry=my-registry --format=json | jq '.credentials
```

You can get this information with other clients or using the [Rest API](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/reference/cloudiot/rest/v1/projects.locations.registries.devices#Device) directly.